# user_id is not taking the value provided

Tags: php, laravel

The migrations file look like below

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

but the posts table in the database is having 0 as value.[image: this shows the database]

The database is populated through the web.php code below. I need the user_id to have values 1 and 2 in the database posts.

```
  Route::get('/create',function (){

    $post=Post::create(['title'=>'lara vel','body'=>'laravel is good for php','user_id'=>1]);
    $post=Post::create(['title'=>'spri ng','body'=>' spring is good for java','user_id'=>2]);

  });
```

Comment: Why do you want user_id to have values 1 and 2?

Comment: Paste you model please!

Comment: And check if user_id is fillable

Comment: @Digvijay Presumably because 2 different user are making posts on the blog/site.

Comment: In that case, let's first fix the migration with `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();`  This will create a foreign key so make sure that user with id 1 & 2 exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's very Simple**

**just Go to your Post model**

*when you use create method to insert data you must be use `fillable` propery in your model.*

*so if you not have an `Post` model so create post Model and paste this code inside your `Post Model`*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'title','body'
    ];
}
```